# How can I choose to download the whole game at once instead of a small part that makes it playable?

Tags: psn

For example, Just Cause 3's total size is 40GB, but it is downloading only the first 5GB to make the beginning of the game playable and then will keep downloading the remaining portion in the background, but I don't want that. What I want to do is download the entire game (40GB) to play it later.

Where can I find that option?

Comment: Just...don't play?

Comment: I'm very confused here.  The game starts loading assets from the beginning first.  Then it just keeps downloading the rest.  Why does it matter that the initial download is the start of the game, not random useless data?

Comment: Does the PSN not continue downloading the entire game once it has the first bit?

Comment: You can't choose, because that's exactly what your console is doing: downloading the entire game at once. It just so happens that the first 5 GB are enough to play the beginning of the game.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have stated, this isn't possible. Take for example, The Surge. As it downloads, two bars appear; one smaller bar, and another larger bar. The smaller portion indicates that the game is in a playable state once that bar is complete, and you can start to play while the rest of the game downloads.

Alternatively, you could simply wait for the rest of the game to download. There is no way to turn this feature off.